# counts per minutes in C

Tags: mysql, c

I have built a Geiger-Mueller counter and its output is connected on the computer parallel physical port #3.
I have a loop that checks for an event on that port. There could be 2-4 pulses in 2ms time frame.
After this line `printf("Radiatie: %.4f uSv\n",(float)sievert);`
I want somehow to execute a mysql insert query every 60 seconds... but that query execution time should not interfere with the for loop.
Any help is welcome, thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BASEPORT 0x378 /* lp1 */
static int  var = 0;
static int C = 1;
static int CPM; /* pulse count */
static float sievert;

int main ()
{
    time_t start_t, end_t; double diff_t;

    if (ioperm(BASEPORT, 3, 1)) {perror("ioperm"); exit(1);}
    outb(0, BASEPORT);
    time(&start_t);

    for( ; ; )
    {
        /* Read from port */
        var = inb(BASEPORT +1);
        if (var == 56)
        {
            /* 56 is the value of HIGH (pulse) */
            CPM = C++;
            printf("%d\n",CPM );
        }
        time(&end_t);
        diff_t = difftime(end_t, start_t);
        int b = (int) diff_t;
        if (b == 60)
        {
            sievert = CPM * 0.0058; /* converting Counts per Minute in uSievert */
            C = 1;
            printf("Radiatie: %.4f uSv\n",(float)sievert);
            time(&start_t);
        }
        /* end for */ 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know hos fast a database insert is, but if you are worried, you might want to create a separate thread for database and/or counter I/O.

Comment: Which current OS allows user-space code to access hardware ports?? Note: this lüikely will be **very** unreliable.

Comment: @Olaf I use Debian. I don't have a better alternative now.

Comment: I'd use a microcontroller and a serial communication port. Easier on PC-side and reliable. Although I'm personally not a fan, Arduino might be a good start. Just my 50ct

Comment: the function 'exit()' is prototyped in stdlib.h.  Therefore, the line: '#include <stdlib.h>' needs to be inserted at the beginning of the code.

Comment: regarding this line: 'printf("Radiatie: %.4f uSv\n",(float)sievert);'  'sievert' is already a float, so no need to cast it.

Comment: regarding this line: 'sievert = CPM * 0.0058;'  0.0058 is being defined as a double, but the result is a float.  Suggest using '0.0058f'

Comment: regarding this line: 'CPM = C++;'  during each minute, at each iteration of the loop,  add 1, 2,3,4,....   when it should only be adding 1 on each iteration of the loop.  Suggest reset CPM to 0 at each minute event , elimination of the 'C' variable, replace the line with: 'CPM++;'

Comment: the code contains a logic problem.   The code seems to want to count the '56' event, however; it counts 'while' input = 56,  which is counting the number of loops executed while input = 56.   It should only count the transition of the input from '0' to '56'.  This implies keeping the history of the input and only incrementing the count when the input changes from 0 to 56

Comment: using *_t for variable names is a very bad programming practice.  (it is also strongly discouraged when defining types, like struct, union, etc)  Suggest removing the '_t' from the end of the variable names

Comment: due to the call to 'ioperm()'  this code must be run in 'privileged' mode.  Is that how you are running the code?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a multithreaded environment in order to be able to both count and run the mysql queries at the same time. You can do this easily using `fork()` and `pipe()` to communicate.

```
int comm[2];
pipe(comm);

if (pid) { // In parent process
    int count;
    int reading_loc = 0, current_read;
    while (current_read = read(comm[0], &count + reading_loc, sizeof(int) - reading_loc)) {
        reading_loc += current_read;
        if (reading_loc == sizeof(int)) {
            reading_loc = 0;
            // GOT FULL VALUE IN COUNT.
            // Run mysql query
        }
    }
} else { // In child process
    while (true) {
        // Do collection stuff
        int value_to_send;
        if (should_run_query) {
            int current_write, writing_loc = 0;
            while (current_write = write(comm[1], &value_to_send + writing_loc, sizeof(int) - writing_loc)) {
                if (current_write == -1) {
                    // Error in the writing process. Be sad :(
                }
                writing_loc += current_write;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a basic outline of how to communicate between the parent and child with a pipe after forking. Your process should be delegated by the system to run in parallel.

Comment: That will still present very unreliable timing.

Comment: I answered the question of how to prevent the sql query from taking up the for loop. The question did not ask about the reliability of the timing.

Comment: I did actually not criticize your approach, but added that as an additional information for OP.

Comment: My apologies... Seemed like a criticism to me.

Comment: regarding: 'pipe(comm); if (pid) { // In child process'   should be: 'pipe(comm); pid_t pid = fork();  if (!pid) { // In child process'  because when pid is 0 then child process.    There should also be a check for 'if(-1 == pid )' to handle the case when fork() fails